# React-Native Image resizeMode contain doesn't work on Android

Tags: react-native

I am using below lines of code to display an image in full window in my application

```
<View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  <Image source={avatarSource}
    style={{width, height}}
    resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} />
</View>
```

The `avatarSource` is a base64 encoded image string. When the app starts, only thumbnails are downloaded for all the images and if the user clicks on the avatar, the full image is shown similar to Whatsapp. If the full image is not present, initially the thumbnail is loaded on the full screen and the full image is downloaded from the server and then once the full image is downloaded, the `avatarSource` is updated and as a result, the full image is shown in the view. This thing works seamlessly on iOS but on Android, once the full image is downloaded, the `Image` component updates itself but doesn't render anything and I just see a white screen. If I remove the `resizeMode` from the `Image`, then the `Image` component updates correctly but I think the default `resizeMode` is `cover` due to which some parts of the image are clipped.

If you have come across this problem or/and have some solution in mind, please share. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try without using width and height in ımage's style

Answer (score 0):

use resizeMode: "contain" as part of the style, so:
style={{width, height, resizeMode: "contain"}}